# Internet Explorer 11 creating empty white space on div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create a print-friendly version of a webpage, however, the webpage and the print preview in Internet Explorer 11 have some mysterious blank space beneath the div's.

I have checked all the CSS classes, html markup, etc.

- Setting the height makes no difference
- Setting margin and padding to 0 makes no difference

It is just a huge white block beneath each div - there's nothing associated with it, so I do not understand why IE is putting it there.

Example:

```
<div class="row"> ## this has the big white space beneath it, after its closing tag
 <div class="medium-12 columns"> ## this is the correct height
  <!-- content -->
 </div>
</div>
## WHITE SPACE HERE ##
## around 20-30 lines long ##
<!-- next div begins here -->
```

CSS rules on the affected tag:

```
padding: 0 0 5px 0;
page-break-inside: avoid;
margin: 0 -.9375rem;
max-width: none;
width: none;
overflow: hidden;
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to why this may be?

Comment: any css to go with this css question? but my guess is: as you have the width of this for 100% (I think that's what the medium-12 col denotes), the div must be inline-block (causing the white space below it)

Comment: Added css for the html affected.

Comment: Can you set up a http://www.bootply.com/ that replicates the error as from what you have shown, we would only be guessing at the problem

Comment: It's in Foundation, not Bootstrap, sorry for the confusion. Inspecting the space brings back just that 'row' div - but if I set a height on that, the div gets reduced to that height then the empty space becomes its own 'entity'.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have tried zeroing out the margins, but I would suggest that You must try and add a reset for your stylesheet. **[CSS resets](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)** remove nearly all browser presets that usually interfere with custom stylesheets that include various types of document styles.

You just need to add it as a separate file link in your document, or simply copy and paste the code in your main CSS file, before all of your custom styles.

There are a few options out there regarding CSS resets, but I think that ***[Mr. Mayer's reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)*** would do the best job here.

Comment: Followed your advice and added the reset, it hasn't fixed the issue - it's still the same. Very odd issue.

Comment: I am assuming that You are applying the CSS to something within the content of your container. Can I see what exactly?

Comment: There's no custom CSS with the exception of the page-break-inside: avoid; Everything else is just using Foundation's "row" which works fine. If I take all the classes off the elements, the issue still persists, which tells me it isn't necessarily the styling. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @JWDev if you are using foundation have you tried no-gutter class (or whatever is called in foundation) to that row?

Comment: They added the no-gutter in v6.1, which we're not using. But even if I take off all of Foundation's classes, the issue remains.

Comment: Or.. you can try adding something like 2px of padding at the bottom of your element, or maybe even a transparent border. Try this and tell me what happens. Give it something to chew on.

Comment: @JWDev I think that the problem (specially with IE) is with the negative rem value that foundation applies to that margin, read my answer above (not a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

As i see that you are using Foundation, i have seen that foundation grid have some kind of issue adding negative margin values like that margin: 0 -0.9375rem;

Basically the 0.9375 is the main margin for your grid, rendered from SCSS to CSS. To avoid additionally compounding margins on nested columns, Foundation applies a negative padding to equalize.

If you're having problems with nested rows, make sure each sub .row is contained withinin a "small-xx ... columns" class, this should bring the edges back to normal.

Don't do this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 columns"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 columns"></div>
    <div class="small-3 columns"></div>
  </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .row -->
```

Instead do this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 columns"></div>
  <div class="small-6 columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-6 columns"></div>
      <div class="small-6 columns"></div>
    </div><!-- .row -->
  </div><!-- .small-6 .columns -->
</div><!-- .row -->
```

Comment: Just tried this too, doesn't make any difference. Even if I explicitly remove the rem value and replace it with some else or remove it altogether, all it does is change the width of the row, the space below it is still intact.